# Polymer get an attribute from an element

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am using neon-animation-pages and I want to see if an attribute is set on one of its child elements.  From what I understand you can just add any attribute you want and if it is in the tag it will resolve to true if it doesn't have a value explicity set.  For instance:

```
<neon-animation-pages id="pages">
    <div awesome>This one is awesome</div>
    <div>This one is not</div>
    <div>This one is not</div>
</neon-animation-pages>
```

Above I created my own attribute called: awesome

In my code I use this:

```
_onIronSelect: function(){
    console.log(this.$.pages.selectedItem.getAttribute('awesome'));
}
```

The console only spits out 'null' or ' ' depending on whether it has my awesome attribute.  I can prob make it work, but I thought it was supposed to resolve to true or false, boolean?

---

Found this in the docs

> Boolean properties are set based on the presence of the attribute: if
>   the attribute exists at all, the property is set to true, regardless
>   of the attribute value. If the attribute is absent, the property gets
>   its default value.

at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html

So I assume I should be trying to get the value of the selectedItem's property > awesome.  How can I do this?

Comment: I guess this is because `awesome` isn't assigned a value `awesome="someValue"`. What to you expect to get from `this.$.pages.selectedItem.getAttribute('awesome')`?

Answer (score 1):

There's an important difference between *properties* and *attributes*. Properties are JavaScript properties on the DOM object. Attributes basically provide a string valued key/value database that can be initialized from markup.

The Polymer docs you quoted are talking about *properties*. If a Polymer element has a property, `awesome`, listed in the `properties` object with a type of `Boolean`, it will deserialize to `true` or `false` as described.

This is a service Polymer provides because it's a common pattern for HTML elements. For example, if you set the `id` *attribute* on an HTML element, the browser automatically *reflects* that to the `id` property. But if you add a generic attribute that that element doesn't know about (like `awesome`), the attribute isn't reflected as a property.

If you want to test for the presence or absence of an attribute on any element (standard HTML or Polymer), use `hasAttribute` as @günter-zöchbauer said. According to MDN, `getAttribute` in all modern browsers returns `null` when the attribute is absent, but apparently this wasn't always true, so `hasAttribute` is probably safer, as well as clearer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want

```
this.$.pages.selectedItem.hasAttribute('awesome')
```

Comment: just realized getAttribute works as it should.  I actually need to get the value or one of the selectedItem's properties